# Dart/Flutter/Hive. Архитектура файлов

Tags: flutter, dart, hive

Всем привет. Решил написать первое подобие юзабельного приложения с локальной БД (остановился на Hive). Но проблема в том, что примеры в доках используют main как стартовый экран, хотя это только точка старта. А в реальных приложениях есть ещё `SplashScreen`. Вобщем, хотелось бы увидеть пример приближенный к боевым.
Три файла:
`**SplashScreen**` здесь переход на главный экран происходит по таймингу.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(
      seconds: 3,
    ), () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(),
      ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FlutterLogo(
          size: 400,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`**HomePage**` пример взят прямо из документации Hive про книги

```
const favoritesBox = 'favorite_books';
const List<String> books = [
  'Harry Potter',
  'To Kill a Mockingbird',
  'The Hunger Games',
];

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox<String>(favoritesBox);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Box<String> favoriteBooksBox;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    favoriteBooksBox = Hive.box(favoritesBox);
  }

  Widget getIcon(int index) {
    if (favoriteBooksBox.containsKey(index)) {
      return Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red);
    }
    return Icon(Icons.favorite_border);
  }

  void onFavoritePress(int index) {
    if (favoriteBooksBox.containsKey(index)) {
      favoriteBooksBox.delete(index);
      return;
    }
    favoriteBooksBox.put(index, books[index]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Favorite Books',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Favorite Books'),
        ),
        body: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: favoriteBooksBox.listenable(),
          builder: (context, Box<String> box, _) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: books.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, listIndex) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(books[listIndex]),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: getIcon(listIndex),
                    onPressed: () => onFavoritePress(listIndex),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Settings** ещё один пример из документации, но пусть это якобы индивидуальные настройки

```
const darkModeBox = 'darkModeTutorial';

void main() async {
        await Hive.initFlutter();
        await Hive.openBox(darkModeBox);
        runApp(MyApp());
    }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: Hive.box(darkModeBox).listenable(),
            builder: (context, box, widget) {
            var darkMode = box.get('darkMode', defaultValue: false);
            return MaterialApp(
                themeMode: darkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
                darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
                home: Scaffold(
                        body: Center(
                            child: Switch(
                                value: darkMode,
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                    box.put('darkMode', !darkMode);
                                },
                            ),
                        ),
                ),
            );
        },
        );
    }
}
```

Как их по уму собрать в кучу? Чтобы `SplashScreen` убирался не по таймингу, а сначало дожидался подгрузки основного экрана и настроек.
Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    Future.wait([
      Hive.initFlutter(),
      Hive.openBox<String>(favoritesBox),
      Hive.openBox(darkModeBox),
      // ...
    ]).then((_) async {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(),
    });
  });
}
```